# How to convert .NET DateTime.toBinary() to java date

Tags: java, .net, date, datetime

I have a .NET INT64 value(result from DateTime.toBinary()) as -8586018589234214115 from JSON response. How do I convert that value into valid java Date?

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: If by *java Date* you meant `java.util.Date`, don’t use that class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4):

The [Binary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary?view=net-5.0) value is:

> A 64-bit signed integer that encodes the [`Kind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Kind) property in a 2-bit field and the [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Ticks) property in a 62-bit field.

Since the `Kind` property is useless to us, we can simply mask it out using `value & ((1L << 62) - 1)` to get the `Ticks` property.

A [Tick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Ticks) is:

> A single tick represents **one hundred nanoseconds** or one ten-millionth of a second. There are `10,000` ticks in a millisecond (see [`TicksPerMillisecond`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tickspermillisecond?view=net-5.0)) and 10 million ticks in a second.
>
> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since `12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001`.

Which means we can convert like this:

```java
private static final long NANOS_PER_TICK = 100L;
private static final long TICKS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000L / NANOS_PER_TICK;
private static final long YEAR_OFFSET = -62135596800L;
// Seconds from Epoch to 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001, calculated using:
//   OffsetDateTime.of(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond()
```

```java
static Instant fromDateTimeBinary(long value) {
    long ticks = value & ((1L << 62) - 1);
    return Instant.ofEpochSecond(ticks / TICKS_PER_SECOND + YEAR_OFFSET,
                                 ticks % TICKS_PER_SECOND * NANOS_PER_TICK);
}
```

*Test*

```java
long dateTimeBinary = -8586018589234214115L;
System.out.println(dateTimeBinary + " -> " + fromDateTimeBinary(dateTimeBinary));
```

*Output*

```
-8586018589234214115 -> 2020-09-10T14:26:02.056169300Z
```

*Warning:* The `-8586018589234214115` value specifies a `Kind` value of `2=Local` *(the time represented is local time)*, but we don't know what the "local" time zone was, so the result of converting to UTC may be wrong.

---

We can also convert the other way:

```java
static long toDateTimeBinary(Instant dateTime) {
    long ticks = (dateTime.getEpochSecond() - YEAR_OFFSET) * TICKS_PER_SECOND
               + dateTime.getNano() / NANOS_PER_TICK;
    return (0x01L/*Kind=UTC*/ << 62) | ticks;
}
```

*Test*

```java
Instant now = Instant.now();
System.out.println(now + " -> " + toDateTimeBinary(now));
```

*Output*

```
2020-12-16T01:51:17.066065200Z -> 5249122821198048556
```

---

*See also:* [Java 8 Time - Equivalent of .NET DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39112535/5221149)

Comment: Thank you very much for the doc link! I have updated [my answer to the linked original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51357072/5772882) accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert the value (e.g. `-8586018589234214115`) to `DateTime` object (say, `theDateTimeObject`) using [`DateTime.FromBinary(Int64)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary?view=net-5.0)
2. Convert `theDateTimeObject` to `DateTimeOffset` as `DateTimeOffset dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(theDateTimeObject, DateTimeKind.Utc)`
3. Pass the value of `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds`
   into [`java.time.Instant#ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-) to get an object of `Instant` which you can convert to other date-time types.

Demo:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long millis = 1608075095347L;
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // You can derive other date-time objects from Instant e.g.
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(zdt);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-15T23:31:35.347Z
2020-12-15T23:31:35.347Z
2020-12-15T23:31:35.347Z
2020-12-15T23:31:35.347
```

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.

If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to convert to unix time [.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0) DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds and then use the java.util.Date [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) constructor to parse it

Comment: It’s a suggestion. I recommend you don’t use `Date` in Java. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).